# How to create controls dynamically and aligned dynamically in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I am working on the iOS application with Swift 4. In that project I have requirement  like, I have to create controls dynamically along with the proper alignment.

For example, I have a button when I click on that button I am hitting the service from that I am getting json data which contains 4 objects. Based on that I have to create controls dynamically and dynamic alignment also should do. I tried lot of examples and tutorials. I didn’t find any solution.

Comment: can you elaborate `dynamic alignment also should do`

Comment: Like, in one user I will get 4 json objects. Based on that I have to create 4 labels and Textfield and a Submit button. For second customer 8 data I will get, based on the count of that array I have to create the controls dynamically. Am I clear now?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code so we can see what the actual problem is?

Comment: Have you looked into [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview)?

Comment: try with @Losiowaty answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

You can use UITableView for that and here is example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var nameArr :[String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate  =  self
    tableview.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func four_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    nameArr.removeAll()
    let nameData = ["First Name","Middle Name","Last Name","DOB"]
    nameArr += nameData
    tableview.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func eight_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    nameArr.removeAll()
    let nameData = ["Salutation","First Name","Middle Name","Last Name","DOB","Gender","Mobile","Email"]
    nameArr += nameData
    tableview.reloadData()
}

}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCells
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArr[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


}
class tableviewCells : UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: It's a nice !! !

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView for the same
Your scenario is like, it may possible that one user having 5 records however another may have 10 or 12 records means you've to work dynamically

if there are 2 buttons which calls 2 different APIs then just manage 2 different array like this

```
var arr1 = NSArray()
var arr2 = NSArray()
var isAPI1Called = Bool()
```

save response of both apis in different array

then just manage flag on button tap and in suitable view like this

```
@IBAction func btn1(_ sender: Any) {
 isAPI1Called = true
self.API1Called()
}

@IBAction func btn2(_ sender: Any) {
isAPI1Called = false
self.API1Called()
}
```

Now use flag in UITableview Delegate like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isAPI1Called
    {
    return arr1.count
    }
    else
    { 
     return arr2.count
    }

}
```

Load UITableviewCell as per your requirement if UI changed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         if isAPI1Called
         {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! UITableviewCell
         //Do your required stuff here
         return cell
         }
         else
         {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! UITableviewCell
         //Do your required stuff here
         return cell
         }

}
```

Hope it will help you
Comment if not get any point